# How do I force %20 instead of + for spaces in form data on submit using only Javascript and/or Jquery

Tags: javascript, forms, query-string, urlencode

There is a long story to this. Short form is, I have a legacy Javascript/JQuery/HTML app that can submit form data as query string variables to a long list of unrelated applications on multiple servers over which I have no control.

`https://www.company1.com?s=this+is+the+data`

As in the example, data is submitted with **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** encoding which replaces spaces with the + sign. Most recipients accept this normally. Some do not and require %20 instead. That's the problem.

I need to force the use of %20 for those problem URLs and am limited to Javascript and related libraries. The logic of parsing out and handling the outlier form destinations is not an issue. I just need to know how to force the use of %20 for the spaces.

*Note: I don't think changing the enctype is the solution as **text/plain** would leave me with the same issue and cause other problems and **multipart/form-data** would leave un-encoded spaces. Maybe I'm wrong?*

## UPDATE (3/20/20)

This is a really goofy and temporary fix. So, I'm not posting it as an answer. (Still hoping for a real solution.)

Basically, I'm using Javascript's `preventDefault()` to hijack all form's submit events. Then, I'm checking for the specific URLs I know will fail if + signs are used.

For those, I'm grabbing the form's `input` name/values, constructing the query string manually and running it through `encodeURIComponent()` which encodes spaces with %20 like I need. Then, together with the form `action`, I can put the whole URI together and shove it across with `window.location.href`.

Please, somebody tell me there's a better way to do this entirely client-side!

Comment: most of the time thats dictated by the browser.

Comment: Write a proxy on the server and ajax to the proxy

Comment: @Daniel A. White - Yeah. I was just hoping there was a way to override the browser dictate other than just changing the enctype.

Comment: @mplungjan - The app is a browser extension that has no server-side component and the servers/applications the requests are going to are 3rd party. As I said in my question, I have no access to them and the list of HTTP request URLs can and must be able to change. So, the solution has to be entirely client-side.

Comment: Have you tried jquery ajax pre-filter?

`jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()`

Description: Handle custom Ajax options or modify existing options before each request is sent and before they are processed by $.ajax().

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

You can perform encoding in that method.

Comment: Hijacking the submit event is the way to go here.